# monitor fs via fswatch

Tags: centos7, fswatch

dnf install epel-release

dnf install fswatch

I want to monitor all changes (create/modify/delete) under /blah/nav_prd and append all updates to /blah/itsbeenchanged

I want to monitor all changes (create/modify/delete) under /blah/nav_prd and append all updates to /blah/itsbeenchanged